# What is the difference between "knickers" and "panties"?

Tags: differences

What is the difference between "knickers" and "panties"? 
I've read the difference is that "knickers" used in the UK and "panties" is used in US. Is this the only difference?

Comment: In the US, "panties" only refer to women's underwear, never men's.

Comment: @Charles The same happens in Japan!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's what I've always assumed. [Wikipedia seems to agree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panties):

> In British English, and in places such as the UK, Ireland, South
>   Africa, India, and occasionally in other Commonwealth nations such as
>   Australia and New Zealand, **panties are often referred to as knickers.
>   The term knickers is not generally used in the US and Canada**, where
>   the term "panties" is usually favored. In the UK, pants is also used,
>   but can mean men's or women's underwear. This should not be confused
>   with the North American usage of pants which are called trousers in
>   the UK.

Comment: This is surprising to me. In India, "knickers" is often used for "knickerbockers" (see JeffSahol's answer) or just any kind of shorts (not underwear).

Comment: In the US, "panties" usually refers to women's garments, while "undies" means either men's or women's garments.

Comment: This is one of us Brits' greatest sources of humour.  For example, when someone from the US gets mud on his or her trousers and exclaims that they need to change their pants.

Comment: Falling into a puddle and getting a wet fanny is also pretty snigger-worthy.

Comment: In BE "panties" rather than pants/knickers has sexual implications. Panties = feminine/lingerie, you wouldn't call what your grandmother wears "panties" but a tabloid newspaper would use them about a young women

Answer (score 5):

As well as the UK/US divide, there's the matter of collocation. We speak of *panty liners* and not *knicker liners*, while on the other hand we speak of *knicker elastic* and not *panty elastic*.

Answer (score 1):

Also knickers , in the US at least, is short for [knickerbockers](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knickerbockers_%28clothing%29).

Comment: Yes, but to my knowledge this is only used to refer to New York City's basketball team (and it's *Knicks*, not *Knickers*). It is otherwise completely out of use here.

Comment: TED, http://www.golfknickers.com/category_s/57.htm

Comment: Probably just because there's a squatter on Golfpants.com . :-)

Answer (score 1):

Panties are used by advertisers in the U.S. to sell women's underwear. Women don't call their underwear panties.

Knickers is a British term for underpants..unless used to refer to old fashioned style clothing that went down to your knees.

Comment: What do women n the US call them then?

Comment: Every woman I know calls them panties, especially if they are particularly frilly, feminine or for girls. Growing up, boys underwear could be called gitch or gotch. I live in central Canada.

Comment: @Mitch: Yendi just has inadequate experience to make such a claim.

Comment: Apparently, I'm not a woman, because I *do* indeed call my underwear "panties". Well, sometimes. Mostly, I just call them underwear.

Answer (score 0):

In the U.S. "knickers" refers to "knickerbockers," or "shorts" for MEN that are OUTERWEAR.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knickerbockers_%28clothing%29

"Panties" refers to "underwear," and specifically to WOMEN's underwear.